# Simplification of nonlinear constraint for optimization

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I solve a nonlinear optimization problem with constraint

$$ \sum_{j=1}^S \ln \Bigg( \Big(1 -x_j c_k + y_j d_k\Big)^2 + \Big( x_j d_k + y_j c_k \Big)^2 \Bigg) \leq 0, \: k = 1, \dots , K $$

where the optimization variables are $\boldsymbol x, \boldsymbol y \in \mathbb R^S$ and the coefficients $\boldsymbol c , \boldsymbol d \in \mathbb R^K$. I derived this constraint from

$$ \prod_{j=1}^S \Big(1 -x_j c_k + y_j d_k\Big)^2 + \Big( x_j d_k + y_j c_k \Big)^2 \leq 1, \: k = 1, \dots , K $$

where the sum of logs seemed more appealing to me than the product of squares.

Does anyone see further simplifications / reformulations of this constraint (e.g. to conic constraints, "less" nonlinear one, ...)?

To be honest, I have not much hope since I think this problem is inherently non-convex for $\boldsymbol x, \boldsymbol y, \boldsymbol c,\boldsymbol d$ taking negative values, but I want to give it a shot, maybe someone sees something.

Comment: As you say, there is most likely no way out of this inherent non-convexity.  Out of curiosity, how large are the problems you want to solve?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/8624/simplification-of-nonlinear-constraint-for-optimization.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg $S$ is less than $100$, while the number of constraints can easily be on the order of thousand.